# How do I utilize user input without putting info into a Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

This is an incredibly newbish question, but I can't seem to find the answer.

I'm building an app that utilizes external APIs heavily, and I'm fairly new to Rails, so it's still a little rough to get around. I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to accept user input and execute a function in my app without writing to a model.

For example, I just want to let a user type in a Twitter username and have it display on the page. I know how to make a form to cache the search in a model, but I can't figure out how to just... make a function happen on a page. I've been breaking my brains on this for several days now.

Please help? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *need* a model to use Rails, but if you don't need ActiveRecord at all, you might benefit from a lighter framework like [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/). That doesn't answer your question, but it's worth thinking about if you really have no database requirement for your application.

It sounds like you're just trying to access non-resourceful user input, which is accessible in the controller via the params hash. So, assuming you have set up a [valid route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for the form action, you use [your controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) to extract GET or POST parameters.

For example:

```
# You define a non-resourceful route in routes.rb for your form action.
get 'twitternames/show'

# Form action directs user to GET the following route after filling in the form.
http://example.com/twitternames/show?user=foo

# The controller action extracts the data.
def show
  @user = params[:user]
  # render the view unless you tell rails to do something else
end

# show.html.erb
<%= @user %>
```

Creating the right route is the key. Once you've defined a route that can break a URL into the proper segments, the rest will fall into place.

Comment: I think this might be the answer I'm looking for. I'll give it a shot once I'm back at my dev setup. Is it generally best to use a new view after a form submission instead of, say, using an AJAX call to update the current page?

Comment: The Rails convention is to use a unique resource (e.g. controller/action pair) for everything because it is more RESTful, but there are definitely use cases where sharing or passing actions, or using AJAX calls to update the DOM, will result in a performance improvement. I don't think this is one of those situations, though. :)